# How to ignore an association field in JSON output when it is not loaded?

Tags: go, model, go-gorm, go-gin

In my gorm models, I have User, and Profile:

```
type User struct {
    ID            int    
    Username      string
    Password      string     `json:"-"`

    Profile Profile
}

type Profile struct {
    UserID        int    
    Gender        string
    Places        string

    //...And many more fields
}
```

When I look for a full display of one's profile by using:

```
db.Preload("Profile").Where("id = ?", 1).First(&user)
c.JSON(200, user)
```

The JSON result which client side will receive is perfectly fine:

```
{
    "ID": 1,
    "Username": {
        "String": "",
        "Valid": false
    },
    "Profile": {
        "UserID": 1,
        "Gender": "men",
        "Places": "Home and staying home",
        // ...And many more
    },
}
```

**But when I want to list only ID and Username two fields, even though I did not Preload() or Related() Profile, there is still an empty set of it:**

```
db.Where("id = ?", 1).First(&user)
c.JSON(200, user) 

// Result
{
    "ID": 1,
    "Username": {
        "String": "",
        "Valid": false
    },
    //below is redundant in this situation
    "Profile": {
        "UserID": 0,
        "Gender": "",
        "Places": "",
        // ...And many more 0 or "" fields
    },
}
```

My question is how to ignore the Profile fields from JSON response every time when it is not loaded? In order to save some transfer cost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use pointer of the struct if you want to omit them. It will make it nil if not loaded, and it will not appear in JSON

```
type User struct {
    ID            int    
    Username      string
    Password      string     `json:"-"`

    Profile *Profile `json:",omitempty"`
}
```